# Android How to set margin in Relativelayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to set margin from top.

```
RelativeLayout root = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.root);        
    listview = new PullListView(getActivity());
    root.addView(listview);
```

How can I set margin of listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams =(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)relativeLayout.getLayoutParams();
relativeParams.setMargins(0, 80, 0, 0);  // left, top, right, bottom
relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use LayoutParams

```
LayoutParams params=(LayoutParams) root.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin=0;
        params.rightMargin=0;
        params.rightMargin=0;
        params.leftMargin=0;
root.setLayoutParams(params);
```